# Can I use Google Cloud Endpoints with external services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, api-gateway

I'm new to the GCP Services, and I'm trying to make an API Gateway to proxy two services, one is run on an App Engine and the other is actually a PaaS.

Can I configure Cloud Endpoints to redirect to that PaaS, and how? and if now what service in GCP suits this case?

Edit:
An example of what I'm trying to do is if my domain is test.com then i'd like app.test.com to be redirected to my App Engine and ip.test.com would be directed for example to https://httpbin.org/ip.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?  I am getting the sense that you want one exposed interface and then direct each request as a function of request to one or other of the backends?  Can you expand your question with more description?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) for securing the endpoint. Set the value that you want in the `x-google-backend`.

I also provide some tips about the URL rewriting if you want.

---

**EDIT 1**

If you want to perform this routing

- app.test.com -> App Engine
- ip.test.com -> External service

You need to use a HTTPS Load Balancer and not API Gateway.

Then,

- create a [serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) and configure it with App Engine
- create an [Internet NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts) and configure it to reach your internet accessible PaaS service
- Create a [URL MAP](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map) with the correct routing

That's all (wait 3 - 5 minutes, the delay to dispatch your configuration around the globe.)

Comment: This does not explain how to use ESP for non-GCP backends.

Comment: Agree, I didn't well understand the question. I update my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. But it's just a re-routing step you explained. Cloud Endpoint can also be used to secure your api. And with this approach you will not gain that.

Comment: Yes, but you can't!! API Gateway work on the path (www.domain.com/path/to/resource). Load Balancer can route based on the (sub)domain. If you want to use API Gateway, rely your routing at the PATH level, and not at the domain level.

Comment: I did not ask the questions but the answer to this question is not "No you can't" and I think is not what yo suggested. @Travis Webb answer is more accurate.

Comment: Yes, you can run ESP anywhere but it won't solve your multiple subdomain routing!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run an [Extensible Service Proxy](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp) in front of your non-GCP backend service so that Cloud Endpoints can proxy requests to it.

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/running-esp-localdev